# Cannot find module 'my_package' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, npm-package

Does anyone have a solution to this npm package issue.

This is what I'm facing:

is present in node_modules after running npm install but I'm not able to use this package.

I'm getting this error: "Cannot find module 'my_package' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)"